# Multiple envelopes open concurrently in DocuSign embedded Send view

Tags: docusignapi

We are building a DocuSign integration using the embedded Send view.  All documents should be sent from a single company email address so that if a customer emails us with a question, they reach the group, not any individual member.  To enable this, we are sending all envelopes from a single DocuSign account.

We encounter a problem when multiple users open envelopes in embedded Send view concurrently - they get logged off because each DocuSign account can only be open in one window at a time.

Is there an account setting to allow multiple embedded Send views to be open simultaneously?

Alternatively, we may have to send documents from different accounts so that multiple users can send envelopes at the same time.  If this is true, is there a way to set up multiple DocuSign accounts with the same email address so that all of our customers receive documents from the same email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting on the account backend (not visable to you at this time) that would allow multiple sessions to be used on the same user. That sounds like it'd resolve your issue.

Kim's answer below also would work if you wanted to use multiple users under the same email.

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign does not allow more than 1 active session for a given set of user credentials (email/password) at any given point in time.

But, you can still achieve your goal -- because DocuSign identifies a user based on combination of email address / name / password.  So, you can create multiple users in the DocuSign account that all use the same email address -- just make sure that you set each of their names to a distinct value when creating the users in DocuSign, and ALSO -- make sure that each user sets their PASSWORD to a UNIQUE value.  For example, I could create 2 users with the following info:

John Doe   |    jdoe@outlook.com
Jane Doe   |    jdoe@outlook.com

When John activates his account, he sets his password to **john123**.
When Jane activates her account, she sets her password to **jane456**.

Both of these users will use the email address **jdoe@outlook.com** to login, but DocuSign will know which user it is logging in based upon the password they enter. Because they're each using a distinct user account, thay can be connected to DocuSign simultaneously without any issues.